# Using inline url() property with Django template {%staric 'img/header/header-1.jpg%}

Tags: html, css, django

I'm having trouble with displaying images with Django templates {%static%}.

```
<div class="slide" style="background: url({% static "images/header/header-1.jpg" %}) center center; background-size: cover;">
```

However, I am successfully able to display an image with  tag

```
<img src={% static "images/logo.png" %} alt="Olga">
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you use the {% static %} in inline styling is just fine. One suggestion (purely cosmetic is to use `'images/header/header-1.jpg'` rather than `" "`).

Here are ways to debug.

1. clear browser history and try again.
2. if 1) does not work, open google chrome developer tool, and see if you have
   `GET ... 404(Not Found)` error. If this is the case, it just means that your file path is wrong. Make sure that when you put

```
<img src={% static "images/header/header-1.jpg" %}>
```

**in the SAME template file**, the image shows up.